# How to access UserInfo object in client app after authenticating with OpenId Connect provider

Tags: authentication, cookies, openid-connect

I'm very new to OAuth and OpenId Connect, I've been reading all I can about it but still not understanding it completely.  I'm working with a client web app that has the ability to authenticate with OpenId Connect with just some simple configuration settings such as the identity provider url, client id, client secret, config endpoint etc. I set that up and I'm using an identity server that has been made available to use for this purpose.  The problem I'm running into is that the client web app is mostly locked down, I don't have access to the source.  I can only make some HTML and Javascript customizations via an admin interface, but I will need to get at some custom data that should be part of the profile JSON coming back from the UserInfo endpoint so I can take some action with it.  Should I expect that the UserInfo profile JSON and/or the token needed to call the UserInfo endpoint be available in a browser cookie or somewhere that I can access it using Javascript?  I've poked around using the F12 debugger and Fiddler but don't see what I need.  Is this even possible without having access to the server-side code in the client web app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access/use roles and custom info from OpenId Connect profile within Dynamics 365 Portal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701294/access-use-roles-and-custom-info-from-openid-connect-profile-within-dynamics-365)

Comment: I asked this question in another SO post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701294/access-use-roles-and-custom-info-from-openid-connect-profile-within-dynamics-365, that was more detailed for my specific situation.  I got an answer via a Microsoft support case and posted it there.