# Access/use roles and custom info from OpenId Connect profile within Dynamics 365 Portal?

Tags: identityserver3, openid-connect, dynamics-crm-online

I am starting to work with Dynamics 365 Portal add-on (Online, not on-prem), which I've configured to use an external authentication provider in the form of Identity Server with OpenId Connect.  The problem with this is that I don't have access to the under-the-hood portal authentication process, there's just a few basic config settings and users can authenticate using the external IdP.  I can't access roles, claims, or any custom info that might come back as part of the OpenId Connect user's profile (userinfo object response).  I need to get at that data to customize the portal user experience.  I've looked through whatever documentation I could find on the portal but can't find anything.  Am I missing something or is it just not possible to access that info and customize the portal login process?  Since it doesn't seem possible to do anything server-side within the portal because it's Online, can I do anything client-side within the portal to get the OpenID access token and call the UserInfo endpoint with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a case open with Microsoft and finally got an answer from them: In Dynamics CRM Online with the Online Portal add-on, there is currently no way to access anything coming back from an external identity provider.  So for example, if you've configured the portal to use an external identity provider such Google, Facebook, etc, or like in my case an Identity Server instance with OpenId Connect, you can't access the claims or any other info coming back from the provider.

UPDATE:
I got another response from Microsoft support: they have confirmed their dev teams are working on making this available but don't have an ETA yet.  At least it's on their radar.